# NextJS middleware cookies issue

Tags: node.js, next.js, middleware

I wanted to check if user has a valid token inside the cookie before accessing **/api** routes on my NextJS app so I created a middleware which would check that.
Somehow I am not able to extract the value from req.cookies in my middleware... I followed NextJS official docs (https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware). First of all TypeScript is already throwing error:  **Error [TypeError]: request.cookies.getAll is not a function** and also **Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'. Did you mean 'valueOf'?ts(2551)**

```
export function middleware(request: NextRequest) {
  const cookie = request.cookies.get("token")?.value;
  console.log(cookie);

  const allCookies = request.cookies.getAll();
  console.log(allCookies);

  const response = NextResponse.next();
  return response;
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: "/api/:path*",
};
```

Comment: I have an error on a similar situation about getAll that doesn't exist on req.cookies with next@12.3.1. Have you tried inspecting what properties are available on the cookies object?

Comment: Can you also show us the imports you have on that file, name the `NextRequest` import?

Comment: It's the standard NextJS request type.
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

Answer (score 0):

It looks like either the docs or the types are incorrect?

The type for `NextCookies` in 12.2.x:

```
export declare class NextCookies extends Cookies {
    response: Request | Response;
    constructor(response: Request | Response);
    get: (key: string) => string | undefined;
    getWithOptions: (key: string) => GetWithOptionsOutput;
    set: (key: string, value: unknown, options?: CookieSerializeOptions | undefined) => this;
    delete: (key: string, options?: CookieSerializeOptions) => boolean;
    clear: (options?: CookieSerializeOptions) => void;
}
```

You'll notice that the method `getAll` is not defined. For what it's worth, I no longer get this error in 13.2.x

Answer (score -3):

You cannot read in middleware the cookie value. You can read the cookie value only server side e.g. getserversideprop

Comment: This is not true according to the documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware#using-cookies

Comment: @rikkit, it really depends. he is correct to a certain degree. With the advent of RSC (React Server Components) and this being NextJS 13 Server Components, many need to understand that middleware is bidirectional. If fetch requests are made in a client component, cookies should be available. However if a fetch request is done from a server component, cookies are null.